# How can I create themes for Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, themes

What makes me feel good in Linux is **customization**. I've recently tested some great themes for Gnome Shell. They're really great, but sometimes I don't like some part of them. I looked into the files and found out that the themes are **CSS-based**. I know CSS, but I don't which classes or IDs refer to which parts of the screen.

Is there any reference or guide for theming Gnome Shell? *(not GTK3)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of an old question, Anyway there is a new GTK GUI inspection tool added with GTK v3.14.

> GtkInspector is the built-in interactive debugging support in GTK+. It was added in GTK+ 3.14, based on a copy of the well-estabished gtkparasite.
>
> To enable the debugger, either start your app with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` in your environment, or run `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true` and launch the debugger with the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcuts.

**Source:** [Gnome Projects: GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector)

It is more convenient to know the runtime GUI shell directly than following code, as many applications out there using chunks to construct GUI dynamically.

I didn't need to use the shortcut running for example `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gedit` brings up the GTK Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

while i also have failed so far to find some type of cheat-sheet for gnome 3.4 themes the posts on [the blog of fp.murphy](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/) where Lucas Romero already has linked to seem to contain plenty of very useful information regarding gnome 3.x and its customization.

some basics worth reading prior to [the post provided by Lucas](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/05/more-gnome-shell-customization.html) can be found in an [ealier post there](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/03/customizing-the-gnome-3-shell.html) giving some simple examples and general overview.

if more specifically geared to gnome shell extensions i found the series of up to now 4 posts all written in september 2012 on [mathematicalcoffee](http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.de/2012/09/gnome-shell-extensions-getting-started.html) very helpful. since gnome 3.4 has brought many api-changes its important to look into recent information regarding gnome customization.