# gnome 41, edit theme, which file?

Tags: gnome, themes, css

Which file is for GNOME 4.1 (GTK) theme changes?

I applied theme [Orchis-grey.tar.xz](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1357889) on GNOME 4.1. I need change just color for chosen line more lighter (example in Evolution email client on image, now it is dark-grey, 1st line).

[image]

I know I can do it in CSS, but no changes when I edited CSS file and applied (re-read) theme by `tweaks`.

`Orchis/gtk-4.0/gtk.css`

Which file is the right file to edit? And which attribute?

Thanks. And happy new year!

Comment: Could you see with [GtkInspector](https://askubuntu.com/a/696580/26246) > CSS .

Comment: @user.dz Thanks, I can see it now, right folder for `GNOME 4.1` is `Orchis/gtk-3.0/...`. What is using `gtk-4.0`?

Comment: @guiverc `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses GNOME 3.36; not 40 (used by 21.10) let alone 41 (you call it GNOME 4.1), or am I missing something ?

Comment: @guiverc I installed GNOME 4.1 (https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-gnome-41-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: Please don't forget that you've removed Ubuntu's capacity to install many security fixes; taking over that responsibility for yourself (or the owner of the PPA having replaced Ubuntu with the 3rd party source for security fixes)...  You can use `ubuntu-security-status` to view the consequences security-wise by your decision.  It may also complicate *release-upgrade* into the future...

Comment: @guiverc I know, it is just for fun and testing now. I am looking forward on next LTS, there will be GNOME 4, so I am trying this environment. And seems it is working well.

Comment: ack & :)    You could have got it via Ubuntu 21.10 which is what I'd suggest, or if it's for *fun* you can always use Ubuntu *jammy* however be aware it's off-topic here (and currently still *GNOME Shell 40.5*) so has fewer support options.